# how to customize ABPersonViewController options?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I added feature for getting user contacts using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, for individualview (ABPersonviewcontroller) once user clicked particular name on tableview of contacts, how to customize "**send message**", "**add to favorites**" etc in individualview? I want to remove "add to favorites" option and i need to give my own actions to "send Message" and for other options. I have checked so many websites, but not helped me hopefully. If anyone awareness on this, Please suggest me how to do this. Thanks